# Interpolating Radian Angles?

Tags: c++, math

If I'm given a start angle of 1.0f, and an end angle of 6.0f, then what I really want to interpolate is not the 5 in between 1 and 6, but the smaller portion.  This will cause counter clockwise interpolation. How can I account of this when interpolating?

Essentially, when given 2 radian angles from 0 to 6.283, how can I know if I should interpolate clockwise or counter clockwise based on which would be "shorter"?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the target angle minus starting angle. If that is greater than PI, go counterclockwise.

Invert the logic if the value is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The reciprocal of any angle θ is θ-π.

So why not just calculate your θ, and θ-π, and see which one is smaller?

BTW: this seems math related, and not related to programming.

Comment: This math is often used in programming. The lines blur.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a programming solution to this math problem:

```
Direction WhichDirection(double start, double finish) {
    return ( std::fmod( (finish - start +2*PI), 2*PI) > PI) ? COUNTER : CLOCK;
}
```