# Interpolating an angle counter clockwise?

Tags: c++

Right now 'm using linear bezier to interpolate angles:

```
    float CardAnimation::valueAt( float valueA, float valueB, float t ) const
    {
        return (1.0f - t) * valueA + t * valueB;
    }

....
if(m_startCard.m_angle != m_endCard.m_angle)
            {
                m_targetCard->m_angle = 
                    valueAt(m_startCard.m_angle, m_endCard.m_angle,m_interval);
            }
```

This works as expected. But here is my problem. If your start angle is 0.5f and you want to go to 6.0f (in radians) then it will go clockwise from 0.5f to 6.0f when really since  6.0f - 0.5f > 3.14f it would be much smarter to go counter clockwise from 0.5f to 6.0f (resulting in moving only 0.78 radians rather than 5.5). What should I do to interpolate counter clockwise if abs(endAngle - startAngle > PI) ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this differ in any significant way from your earlier questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/6147839/2509 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6143964/2509 ?

Comment: If you truly believe that then the source of your difficulty is that you have not correctly stated the problem yet, as they are all instances of the same task: *"Identify the arc between two arbitrary angles"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `abs(endAngle - startAngle) > PI`, then subtract `2*PI` from `endAngle`. Then instead of going from `0.5` to `6.0`, you go from `0.5` to `-0.28`.

**Edit:**

This actually assumes `0 <= startAngle < endAngle <= 2*Pi`.

If `0 <= endAngle < startAngle <= 2*Pi` and `startAngle - endAngle > PI`, then **add** `2*PI` to `endAngle`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

1. Normalize all angles to lie in `[0, 2Pi)` by adding or subtracting `2Pi` repeatedly.
2. Shift by `min(a, b)` so that your new endpoints are `0` and `c`.
3. You either want your range to be `c` or by `2Pi - c`, whichever is smaller, and you have to figure out the sign depending on what you did at (2). Then you want to interpolate between your original start point, and the startpoint plus the range.

Comment: Milo: Translate. Add. E.g. (a, b) becomes (0, b-a) if a is smaller.